# Setting Facebook username in sqlmembership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, membership-provider

I'm using Facebook connect and registering users once they login (I add them into my database).

I'm using sqlmembership provider. Currently I'm getting the Facebook user's full name and using it as the username. But the problem I'm having is if 2 people have the same name it won't register the second user.

How should I handle the username? I'm thinking append the Facebook id then truncate when using the username in the site? A bit ugly but can't think of a better way.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You would need the facebook ID; you could store it in session, or create a custom IPrincipal and/or IIdentity and store it with the user info.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a custom Sql Membership Provider, i am using that scheme myself for my application, that way you have a fine grain control of the way you wanna store your data.
Have a look at

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

&

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-profile-provider

Answer (score 0):

why use something that is likely to change (the persons name). people get married, or put silly nicknames for themselves which some people change frequently.

why not use just the ID? you can always make another table (outside of SqlMembership) to store the most recent name for that user

Comment: if I do this how should i handle showing the different usernames. eg my site registered users will show their usernames whilst it would show a facebookID for facebook users when i use: Context.User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while ago.

This is my table:

```
FacebookUniqueID BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY
FacebookEmail    NVARCHAR(100), NULL
```

I also store other things for auditing, but that is the key info.

Now, you will *always* get the Facebook user id. But you won't *always* get the user's email address - because they can deny access - hence I allow NULLs.

The reason I store email is that Unique ID is not enough to marry the user up to the user in your system.

In the SqlMembershipProvider, the username is normally the email. So I use the "FacebookEmail" field to link the user.

If they don't allow you their email address, you're not going to be able to perform a single sign on (e.g auto sign them into your website when they are authenticated into Facebook).

But at least if they eventually grant you the permission, you can update the email field in your DB and then perform the single sign on.